# Working with Variables

Tags: plugin-development, variable

How do I display a variable in my template?

I have the following code:

```
<?php
namespace Craft;

class HelloPlugin extends BasePlugin
{
    function getName()
    {
         return Craft::t('Hello');
    }

    function getVersion()
    {
        return '1.0';
    }

    function getDeveloper()
    {
        return 'Richard G.';
    }

    function getDeveloperUrl()
    {
        return 'http://example.com';
    }

        public function hasCpSection()
    {
        return true;
    }

}

plugins/hello/variables/HelloVariable

<?php
namespace Craft;

class HelloVariable
{
    // property
    $message = 'Hello, World";"
 }


plugins/hello/templates/index.html

{% extends "_layouts/cp" %}

{% set title = "Hello World"|t %}

{% set content %}

<h2>MessageVariable  {{ craft.helloPlugin.HelloVariable.message }}</h2>

{% endset %}
```

Answer (score 6):

Within your variables class file you will want to define methods that 'return' values to your template, like so:

```
class HelloVariable
{
    public function message()
    {
        return "Hello, world!";
    }
}
```

Which you would call from your template using:

```
{{ craft.hello.message }}
```

On a side note, a really good place to start plugin development is to download and install a plugin template such as [BusinessLogic](https://github.com/lindseydiloreto/craft-businesslogic), which provides a basic plugin structure, some sample files, and includes inline documentation for basic business logic kind of functionality.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to `BusinessLogic`. Pure gold!

Answer (score 1):

Here is my corrected code ...

```
<?php
namespace Craft;

class HelloVariable
{
    public function getMessage($msg)
    {
        return $msg;
    }
 }
```

and for the template...

```
{% extends "_layouts/cp" %}

{% set title = "Hello World"|t %}

{% set content %}

<h2>{{ craft.hello.getMessage('Say something original...') }}</h2>

{% endset %}
```

which prints in the control panel...

```
 Hello World
Say something original...
```